# Can we use Custom Metadata Types in Group Edition?

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata, editions, group-edition

We have a managed package currently using custom settings, and it has been installed in all editions except Database.com, i.e. Group, Professional, Performance, Unlimited and of course Developer.

We are interested in using custom metadata types to store some application configuration details, but according to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=0), custom metadata types are not available in Group edition.

Therefore, if I package custom metadata types with the managed package, will it prevent Group edition owners from upgrading or installing the package?

Also, I just created an Partner Group edition, and I can actually see the Custom Metadata Types menu in the setup? Could it be that the documentation is out of date?

Comment: When the metadata your are updating or installing via managed package it will throw run time error if it is not supported in that org. Also it should be available in all types of edition where we can write apex but I am not sure on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc is inaccurate; I'll let our writer know. Group Edition is like Professional Edition with respect to custom metadata types; they can't create their own but can install them from Aloha-certified managed packages.